# Effect of email address on spam filters

Tags: email, spam, bulk-email

I am setting up a newsletter mailing list for a company and an interesting question came up,

> Does the email address that we send our newsletter from have an effect on whether we get filtered out as spam?

I don't have a whole lot of knowledge in this field but I would like to start a discussion on the matter.

Obviously these are going to be some extreme examples, but if they were to start sending their newsletter from one of the following addresses, what results would you expect from a spam filter were you to start sending newsletters from say:

> `bot@example.com`
>   `scam@example.com`
>   `nigerianprince@example.com`

Would this be any different to something simple like:

> `newsletter@example.com`

Let me know what you think, I haven't been able to find any sources on the matter, and spam filter code tends to be kept private, and for good reason.